# Can you wire something in parallel to a light switch?

Tags: wiring, junction-box, ip-camera

I’m looking to wire a Ring motion camera to the roof overhanging my garage to replace my old Ethernet driven camera. The easiest access wire that I can see is attached to a switch in the attic.

I don’t want the camera to shut off with the switch, so I think that I need to splice the line before the switch so that it’s in parallel.

I’ve been reviewing junction box installation tutorials all day, so I think this should be okay, but are there any gotcha’s I might be unaware of?

Comment: Turn off the circuit breaker controlling the circuit the switch is on, unscrew the mounting screws (only, leave all wires connected) and gently pull the switch far enough out of the box to take clear pictures showing the connections and wiring. Then [edit] those into your question using the "sun and mountains" icon above the edit box. Also, where on the planet? Wiring practices and conventions are quite different in different parts of the world.

Answer (score 4):

One quite common "gotcha" is that the switch may not have a complete power connection for you to splice to. If the switch was installed at a time or in an area where NEC 2011 did not (or does not) apply, there may be no neutral wire at the switch, due to "switch loop wiring" in the old way where white is always-hot, black is switched-hot, and neutral is only available at the light fixture. (North American colors.)

Or, the switch may be a 3-way switch, (where multiple switches control the same things) in which case there's 50% odds you don't even have an unswitched hot wire available. *And* you might also not have a neutral available.